# Is "apps" a concatenation?

Tags: abbreviations, linguistics

I am aware that "apps" is commonly used as a plural form of "app" in this time and age, which in itself is an abbreviation of "application". But if I assume that "apps" is actually formed from "application software" in a given text, would that technically make it a concatenation? Would it not have to be "applicationsoftware" to qualify as a concatenation? If it's not a concatenation, then what is "apps" in this type of usage? Yet another abbreviation? Would it not have to be "app.s." to qualify as an abbreviation?

```
usage 1:
singular: app (application) plural: apps (applications)

usage 2:
singular: apps (application software) plural: apps (application software)
```

*In some languages "software" has a plural form of "softwares" (languages that loan this word from English). But this is not standard in English. I have therefore not used it above.*

Comment: I've never seen "apps" used to mean "application software".  If you use it to mean that, no one will know what you mean.

Comment: I have never heard of *apps* being formed from "application software"

Comment: Yes, I know it's confusing. But the question is if it would qualify as a concatenation? Or as abbreviation? I would like to know what something like that would be called, technically (or linguistically). And if "app" (usage 1) is an abbreviation, why does it not have a full stop at the end? Is it accepted as a word nowadays, much like "google" is?

Comment: Why does it matter?  Many constructions don't fall into any neat category.

Comment: If you wanted an abbreviation for application software I'd use AppSw

Comment: @HotLicks No, it does not matter. Nothing ever really does. The Sun will still rise the next morning. I am only curious. So if anything, it matters for my understanding of the world around me and the use of the English language.

Comment: Understand that things like "abbreviation" and "concatenation" are simply terms invented by the wordies into which they attempt to stuff parts of the language.  Very often these parts don't fit.

Comment: But surely, there is nothing wrong with trying to categorize things? I wonder if the term "concatenation" is even related to "abbreviation"...

Comment: I've never even heard of "concatenation" being used as a technical term for this supposed linguistic phenomenon. I think "concatenation" is used as a technical term in *computer science*.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, you are probably right. Concatenation is more of a computer term. I'm not sure if it's ever used in linguistics. Well, at least not for natural languages. I don't know about computer languages or computer science. Although computer language designers heavily borrow concepts and terminology from linguistics. The term "contraction" is similar in concept to a concatenation, but it relates only to dropping the middle part of single words. Contractions in English are commonly signified by apostrophe: e.g. it's, he's, etc. But they are used for abbreviations too, without apostrophe.

Comment: If a lemon had four legs and a trunk, would it be an elephant? That seems to me as sensible a question as yours. A false antecedent entails any consequent you life.

Comment: That would make it a lemophant. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If I am to be the judge, I would say that it's both a *concatenation* **and** an *abbreviation*.

```
full form:     application software
concatenation: applicationsoftware
abbreviation:  apps.
abbreviation:  apps
```

There is a term called "contraction" that's used when the middle part of a single word is dropped. But unless you consider the space to be a character (letter) with meaning, like a string literal in a programming language, I don't think "contraction" will fit here. So I would call this a concatenation, which is then abbreviated to "apps", with the full stop (point) dropped in its final form.

Comment: I would just say, that no matter what you want to call it, I suggest that you do not use *apps* as a shortened form for *application software*.  It isn't standard and won't be recognized. And even if you were to write a paper in which the term was used and explained, it  would not catch on with the rest of the software industry.